# Sorting large std::vector of custom objects

Tags: c++, sorting

I am creating a sparse matrix in CSR format, for which I start with a vector of matrix element structures. It needs to be std::vector at the beginning because I don't know ahead of time how many non-zeros my matrix is going to have. Then, to fill up the appropriate arrays for the CSR matrix, I need to first sort this array of non-zeros, in the order they appear in the matrix if one goes through it line-by-line. But above a certain matrix size (roughly 1 500 000 non-zeros), the sorted vector does not start from the beginning of the matrix. It is still sorted, but starts around row 44000.

```
// Matrix element struct:
struct mel
{
  int Ncols;
  int row,col;
  MKL_Complex16 val;
  void print();
};

// Custom function for sorting:
struct less_than_MElem
{
  inline bool operator() (const mel& ME1, const mel& ME2)
  {
    return ( ( ME1.row*ME1.Ncols+ME1.col ) <  ( ME2.row*ME2.Ncols+ME2.col ) );
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<mel> mevec;
  /* long piece of code that fills up mevec */
  std::sort( mevec.begin(), mevec.end(), less_than_MElem() );

  return 0;
}
```

I thought maybe as the vector was grown dynamically it wound up in separate blocks in the memory and the iterator wasn't pointing at the genuine beginning/end anymore. So I have tried creating a new vector and started with resizing it to the size that is known by that time. Then copied the elements one-by-one into this new vector and sorted it, but the result was the same.

```
Nelements = mevec.size();
std::vector<mel> nzeros;
nzeros.resize(Nelements);
for( int i = 0; i < Nelements; i++ )
{
  nzeros[i].Ncols = mevec[i].Ncols;
  nzeros[i].row = mevec[i].row;
  nzeros[i].col = mevec[i].col;
  nzeros[i].val = mevec[i].val;
}

  std::sort( nzeros.begin(), nzeros.end(), less_than_MElem() );
```

Can anyone think of a solution?

Comment: `std::vector` always stores its elements in a single contiguous block of memory. Are you sure your vector is correct before you call `std::sort`? Please provide a [mcve]. Your copy is unnecessary but if you really need it then `std::vector<mel> nzeros = mevec;` should work.

Comment: You really don't want to store the number of matrix columns in each nonzero element. Also, if you need to process the resulting matrix (in CSR format) by the MKL, you likely need 3 separate arrays for values, column indexes, and row pointers.

Comment: *long piece of code that fills up mevec* -- No.  Post code that fills even 5 or 10 items.  Don't assume that this comment is telling the truth as to whether those items are filled correctly.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your matrix (number of rows/columns)? Are you sure that `ME1.row*ME1.Ncols+ME1.col` doesn't overflow a range of `int` data type? If will happen, for instance, for _100k × 100k_ matrix, which is not very large.

Comment: What platform (PC/Mac/Raspberry Pi/etc) and compiler are you using?

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! The problem was indeed that NxN overflew the range of int. Using long long int solved it. Daniel Langr, I'm aware that I don't need to store the matrix dimensions with each element, it is a working progress and at this moment I have no memory issues, but thank you for your remark.

Comment: instead of using a long long, you should rewrite the comparison without a multiply. `if row1 < row2 or row1 == row2 and col1 < col2`.

Comment: good idea, that buys me a power of 2 immediately